# display ticks (values) dynamically on both axes, aligned in the centre

Tags: reactjs, recharts

i want to display ticks on both the x and y axes, aligned in the centre of the graph (to properly display 4 quadrants. I am using react recharts library.
Currently I am using refrence line to show 4 quadrants and the x and y axis are seperate.
How can i display ticks along with values?
Note that the data is dynamically rendered from backend, so the axis can have negative x values and negative y values as well.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  LineChart,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  Line,
  Tooltip,
  ReferenceLine,
} from 'recharts';

const Chart = ({ chartData }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(chartData);

    return () => {

    }
  }, []);

  const gradientOffset = () => {
    const dataMax = Math.max(...chartData.map((i) => i.uv));
    const dataMin = Math.min(...chartData.map((i) => i.uv));

    if (dataMax <= 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    if (dataMin >= 0) {
      return 1;
    }

    return dataMax / (dataMax - dataMin);
  };

  const off = gradientOffset();

  return (
    <>
      <LineChart
        width={1000}
        height={500}
        data={chartData}
        margin={{
          top: 10,
          right: 30,
          left: 30,
          bottom: 10,
        }}
      >

        <defs>
          <linearGradient id="colorUv" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
            <stop offset="50%" stopColor="green" />
            {/* <stop offset="50%" stopColor="green" /> */}
            {/* <stop offset="50%" stopColor="black" /> */}
            {/* <stop offset="50%" stopColor="red" /> */}
            <stop offset="100%" stopColor="red" />
          </linearGradient>
        </defs>

        <XAxis
          dataKey="x"
          domain={['auto', 'auto']}
          interval={0}
          type="number"
        />


        <ReferenceLine y={0} stroke='white' strokeDasharray='none' />

        <ReferenceLine x={0} stroke='white' strokeDasharray='none' />

        <YAxis
          dataKey="y"
          domain={['auto', 'auto']}
          type="number"
          interval={0}
          label={{
            style: { textAnchor: 'middle' },
            position: 'left',
            offset: 0,
          }}
        />

        {chartData.length >= 1 &&
          <Line
            type='monotone'
            dataKey='y'
            stroke='url(#colorUv)'
            strokeWidth={2}
          />}

        <Tooltip
          content={(dataItem) => {
            if (dataItem.payload && dataItem.payload.length > 0) {
              const xValue = dataItem.payload[0].payload.x;
              const yValue = dataItem.payload[0].payload.y;

              const color = yValue < 0 ? 'red' : 'green';

              return (
                <div
                  style={{
                    background: color,
                    color: 'black',
                    border: '1px solid #ccc',
                    borderRadius: '5px',
                    boxShadow: '2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
                    padding: '10px',
                  }}
                >
                  <p style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', marginBottom: '5px' }}>X: {xValue}</p>
                  <p style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', marginBottom: '5px' }}>Y: {yValue}</p>
                </div>
              );
            }
            return null;
          }}
        />
      </LineChart>
    </>
  );
};

export default Chart;
```

Comment: This might help https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/CustomizedLabelLineChart